# Testing if an object is a string

Tags: ruby, coding-style

I have a function that manipulates a string; however, sometimes my input isn't already a string. For example it could be a path object. I need to convert it to a string because I want to call methods like `.gsub`.

My question seems a bit simple, but I'm debating on the best approach for converting the object to a string.

I currently have two options:

```
str = str.to_s unless str.is_a? String
```

or

```
str = str.to_s
```

The second method is much simpler, but the first method actually describes what's going on. I'm wondering which of these two methods is better to use or if there's a better approach I haven't thought of?

Comment: The fact that `String#to_s` is defined is a message from the developer of Ruby that you should go with the second one. Cases like this is the only case where `String#to_s` would be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would prefer the second one.

I'd prefer the parameter/variable wasn't named `str` if it isn't a string.

Naming it `str` *implies* string, but then the code looks silly, and is harder to reason about.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer second one. It is shorter, simplier and also describes what you want (any programmer will understand what will heppen). Also there is no notable difference in perfomance.

Answer (score 1):

Go for the second approach without hesitation.

The first one is convoluted and doesn't really add any meaning.